# Objective C: AES 256 Encryption with NSData Keyvalue

Tags: objective-c, encryption

I want to do AES 256 encryption with a NSDATA Key. But everywhere I am finding example with NSString key. Now, how to use NSData key ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use bytes as key. You have to use a string as key. Although, you can convert NSData bytes into a string. But note that the data has to be encoding with some valid string encoding.

Then you can use the following method to convert your NSData to a string , to use as  a key.

```
NSString* newStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: That's the problem. The data file is encoded with Base64. So i can not use utf8 or utf32. Is there any easy way to convert data to string with base64 ??

Comment: Ok.. Try this link by Matt Gallagher-  http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html